# Format matrix into txt file with appropriate blank lines

Tags: matlab, matrix

I am working with a triangulation program and I need to plot the data points and their triangulation (obtained from another program). So I have my delauany edges matrix **newgrid1_eDT** (e for edge list) as (first column is line number):

```
1         0 0   9
2         0 1   9
3         0 1   9
4         0 1   8
5         0 1   8
         [...]
11716     5 6   8
11717     1 2   4
11718     0 2   4
```

and the idea is to make it like this newgrid1_ASCIIeDT:

```
1         0 0   9
2         0 1   9
3
4         0 1   9
5         0 1   8
6
7         0 1   8
         [...]
11715     5 6   8
11716
11717     1 2   4
11718     0 2   4
```

Basically, each 2 rows represent a 3d coordinate pair (and each pair of points represents a line).

I have written the following in an attempt to copy two rows (index i) consecutively from **newgrid1_*eDT*** followed by a blank line to **newgrid1_ASCIIeDT** (index j), thus looping through the empy matrix **newgrid1_*ASCIIeDT*** filling it gradually. I have allocated 11718+ 11718/3 =15624 rows in the recieving matrix **newgrid1_ASCIIeDT**; one for each point we tranfer over from **newgrid1__eDT** plus one empty mrow after every 2 lines (at rows 3,6,9,... and so on):

```
newgrid1__ASCIIeDT=zeros(15624,3);
[m,l]=size(newgrid1__ASCIIeDT) ;
j=0;
i=1;
for  j = 1:3:15624
i   
newgrid1__ASCIIeDT(j,:)=newgrid1__eDT(i,:);
newgrid1__ASCIIeDT(j+1,:)=newgrid1__eDT(i+1,:);
newgrid1__ASCIIeDT(j+2,:)=blank;
i=i+1
end
```

For some reason I am convinced this should do the trick but somehow I get weird results. Are there any other (simpler ways) of doing this or am I reinventing the wheel?

Ideally I would have written this in C (where all the other stuff is happening) but I just need a quick fix at the moment and cant go through 11k lines to introduce blank lines. Any help please ?

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is to put `i = i+2;`

but really, I think you should do

```
newgrid1__ASCIIeDT(1:3:end,:)=newgrid1__eDT(1:2:end,:);
newgrid1__ASCIIeDT(2:3:end,:)=newgrid1__eDT(2:2:end,:);
```

For this to work, `newgrid1__ASCIIeDT` must be initialized to the proper size.  Note that there are 3 lines for every two lines of `newgrid1__EDT`.

Comment: I have tried your suggestion but somehow get the following error 'Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch.' I tried initialising **newgrid1__ASCIIeDT** as an empty matrix (I know this isn't optimal) but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Then the size of newgrid1_ASCIIeDT is not correct.  Actually, it should be 11718 + 11718/2, since you are adding one line for every two elements in the original.